# Horizontal Wizard Navigation with specific width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a horizontal wizard navigation that works just fine, but there are some requirements with styles I failed to achieve.

My code:

```css
.WizardNavigation {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  flex: auto;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item .WizardNavigation__Point {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item~.WizardNavigation__Item .WizardNavigation__Line {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item.WizardNavigation__Item--active .WizardNavigation__Point {
  background: blue;
  color: 1px solid blue;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item--active~.WizardNavigation__Item .WizardNavigation__Point {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item--active~.WizardNavigation__Item .WizardNavigation__Line {
  background-color: gray;
}

.WizardNavigation span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="WizardNavigation">
  <div class="WizardNavigation__Item" style="width: 25%;">
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Point" role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="WizardNavigation__Item" style="width: 25%;">
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Point" role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="WizardNavigation__Item WizardNavigation__Item--active" style="width: 25%;">
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Point" role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="WizardNavigation__Item" style="width: 25%;">
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Point" role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
    <div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is my current navigation.
What I want to do is that the first point is at the start of the parent div and the last point at the end of the parent div. At the moment they have an offset because they are in the middle of the item div.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem?
I'm using react to do it so a javascript solution would also work.

Comment: could you please rephrase what you want to achieve? I'm having hard times understanding that. I'm quite sure it can be achieved with just css styling

Comment: I updated my question, could you check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I'm understanding, the issue is that this thing isn't as wide as the parent. Here's one solution...

Step 1: get rid of the inline width style

Step 2: get rid of the `<div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>`s

Step 3: add the following to `.WizardNavigation`

```
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Step 4: Get rid of this from `.WizardNavigation .WizardNavigation__Item`

```
text-align: center;
flex: auto;
```

Step 5: Add something back to replace your `<div class="WizardNavigation__Line"></div>` elements. We'll use pseudo elements on the `.WizardNavigation__Item--active` element.

```
.WizardNavigation__Item--active:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    background-color: blue;
    top: 6px;
    z-index: 0;  
    width: 100vw;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
.WizardNavigation__Item--active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    background-color: blue;
    top: 6px;
    z-index: 0;  
    width: 100vw;
    left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

I think that's it... See here: https://jsfiddle.net/rk6r7bwm/6/

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. If you look at my example you can see that the line after the active step is gray and not blue. The line is blue until the current step and gray afterwards

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you!